# 2003 civic si - ground control installation on bilstein struts

Tags: honda, suspension, struts

I recently purchased a set of ground control coilover conversion springs to be used with my bilstein struts. The kit came with install instructions for koni yellow struts, which are similar, yet different enough to require a special bilstein kit as opposed to their popular koni yellow kit. The rears seem to have installed just fine with the included instructions, but on the front struts, after installing, theres still a few inches of clearance between the provided tophat and the strut mount.

Do any of you know if theres bilstein specific instructions? I tried searching online and could not find any. I'm wondering if I'm either installing them wrong or if I'm missing some sort of spacer. I will call them on monday and ask, but I was really hoping to knock out this repair this weekend :(

If anyone here has experience with this setup, any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is that clearance you mention for suspension travel? If it was 1/2" then I would thing something was installed incorrectly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "travel" -- I'm trying to say theres a gap between the top hat and strut mount. Even with lowering springs where you can usually remove them without a spring compressor (although I never would), the springs still sit snug between the top and bottom spring mounts once the strut mount is put on. But not in this case.

Comment: Travel is the movement of the suspension between lower limit and upper limit. Most cars are 8 to 12 inches but some 4x4 are some 22 inches.